# How to register a custom Intent filter to a broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have defined a receiver in AndroidManifest.xml to receive a `PlAY_FINISHED` action, and in other file I send an intent to that broadcast receiver like follows:

```
public String PlAY_FINISHED = "play finished"; 
...
Intent in = new Intent(PlAY_FINISHED);
this.service.sendBroadcast(in);
```

so in my manifest file, i set it like this, where MyStaticString is a class that contains all the static string in the application. Is this the correct way?

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mysite.appname.MyStaticString.PLAY_FINISHED" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 13):

The `android:name` of an intent filter in the manifest is just an arbitrary string, not the "path" to a Java constant. The problem is that your string constant in code is defined as `"play finished"`, which doesn't match the name `"com.mysite.appname.MyStaticString.PLAY_FINISHED"` that you've specified in the manifest.

It should be

```
public String PlAY_FINISHED = "com.mysite.appname.MyStaticString.PLAY_FINISHED";
```

It doesn't matter what the variable is called, or even if you store the string in a variable at all. Or that its name contains a typo :)

You could instead change the `android:name` in the manifest to `"play finished"`, but custom broadcast actions are system-wide so they should be qualified with the package name of your app to avoid collisions with other apps.

Comment: So it's not so "arbitrary" if prefixing with package name has an influence on how it works.

Comment: I wouldn't say it has a specific influence on how it works; it just decreases the likelihood of another app using the same string.

Answer (score 5):

**Registering in Android Manifest file.**

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiverDemo">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="marakana.intent.action.ReceiverDemo" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Registering programmatically.**

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ...
  // Create the receiver
  receiver = new TimelineReceiver();
  filter = new IntentFilter( UpdaterService.NEW_STATUS_INTENT );
}

protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter,
      "com.marakana.yamba.SEND_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS", null);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
...
```

UPDATE: **Multiple values
    If more than one value can be specified, the element is almost always repeated, rather than listing multiple values within a single element. For example, an intent filter can list several actions:**

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
    . . .
</intent-filter>
```

UPDATE2: **That's an example of AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest
  package="com.marakana.android.lifecycle"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

  <application
    android:name=".ApplicationDemo"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
      android:name=".ActivityDemo"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".SystemServicesDemo"></activity>

    <service android:name=".ServiceDemo"></service>

    <service android:name=".IntentServiceDemo">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="marakana.intent.action.IntentServiceDemo" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".ReceiverDemo">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="marakana.intent.action.ReceiverDemo" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider
      android:name=".ProviderDemo"
      android:authorities="com.marakana.android.lifecycle.providerdemo" />

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I still don't quite get it, what does marakana.intent.action.ReceiverDemo represent?

Comment: yes..but in my case how should i receiver this intent `Intent in = new Intent(PlAY_FINISHED);`? this is all i want to know...

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(PLAY_FINISHED);`

...

`private void onPlayFinished(){
  Intent iFinished=new Intent(PLAY_FINISHED);
  sendBroadcast(iFinished);
 }`
 To sum it up: You need to set up an activity that creates an intent and then sends an intent using sendBroadcast(intent).

Comment: thanks, for all your answers, but my question is, as indicated in title, how to write my <intent-filter> in manifest.xml, I have pasted my code there, but no intent is received...

Comment: Paste the reciever here, please.